# how to find the lim of $(1+\arcsin x) ^{\cot x} $ as $x$ goes to $0$?

Tags: analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \ln (1+\arcsin x) ^{\cot x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \cot x \ln (1+\arcsin x)=\lim 
\frac{(1+\arcsin x)}{\tan x}$$ from l'hospital

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ \frac{1} {\sqrt{1-x^2}}} {\sec^2 x} $$ is it true?

Comment: you had errors in latex which I have fixed and from the corrected equation you can see that the limit of $\ln$ expression is $1$ so that the original limit is $e$.

Comment: You have this in your post: `$\frac{(\frac{1} {\frac{1}{{1-x^2} }}{sec^2x}$` which does not render because of unpaired {. Did you want to write something like `$\frac{1/\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sec^2 x}$` $\frac{1/\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sec^2 x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : You can write the expression as

$$(1+\arcsin(x))^{\frac{1}{\arcsin(x)} \times {\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\tan(x)}}}$$

and $\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\tan(x)}$ tends to $1$, so you finally get $e$ as the limit.

Comment: it tends to 1 from l hospital right?

Comment: Yes, you can also use the taylor-expansions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the good old taylor series:

$$A:= (1+\arcsin x) ^{\cot x} \implies \ln(A) = \ln((1+\arcsin x)) \cot(x) $$

If $x$ is small, which is true in this case because $x \to 0$, I can approximate this as

$$\ln(A) = \ln(1+x)\cot(x) + O(x^2) = \ln(1+x) \frac{1}{x} + O(x^2) = \frac{x}{x} + O(x^2) =1 + O(x^2)$$

$$\implies \lim_{x \to 0} \, \ln(A) = 1 \implies A= e $$

If you don't like the big $O$ notation above you can change equal signs with approximation signs and live the $O(x^2)$ terms out. Since the approximation gets better and better as $x \to 0$ it won't be a problem to do so.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0} (1+\arcsin x) ^{\cot x}&=\lim_{x\to 0} e^{{\cot x}\ln(1+\arcsin x) }\\&=\exp\lim_{x\to 0} ({\cot x}\ln(1+\arcsin x) )\\&=\exp\lim_{x\to 0} ({\cot x\arcsin x}(\ln(1+\arcsin x))/(\arcsin x) )\\&=\exp\lim_{x\to0}({\cot x\arcsin x} )\tag{$\because \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}x=1$}\\&=\exp\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\arcsin x}{\tan x }\right)\\&=\exp\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1/\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sec^2x}\right)\tag{L'Hospital}\\&=\large \rm e
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to 0} (1+\arcsin x)^{\cot x}=\lim_{x\to 0}  (1+ x + \cdots)^{\dfrac{1}{x} + \cdots}= e$ now take the logarithm we get

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\ln  (1+\arcsin x)^{\cot x}= 1 .$$